# Não permitir a inserção de uma data posterior a outra já inserida

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho um formulário em HTML no qual dou a possibilidade ao utilizador de inserir uma data inicio e uma data fim e, como é óbvio, não quero que a data fim seja anterior à data inicio.

Os inputs para as datas são do tipo "datetime-local". O meu objetivo seria, após a inserção da **Data Inicio**, os campos com os dias anteriores ao dia inserido na Data Inicio aparecessem como "bloqueados" ou assim.

Código:

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="date-form1">Data/Hora Inicio</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="datetime-local" name="date-beginning" id="date-form1">
</div>

<!-- Data Fim -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="date-form2">Data/Hora Fim</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="datetime-local" name="date-end" id="date-form2">
</div>
```

Comment: Você usa alguma biblioteca JS para manipular datas? Tipo momentjs e afins.

Comment: Não, não estou a usar nenhuma biblioteca @jbueno

Comment: Oi Vitor, *inputs* do tipo `datetime-local` possuem um atributo chamado [`min`](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/input.datetime-local.html#input.datetime-local.attrs.min). Você pode fazer *binding* desse atributo em `date-end` com o valor de `date-beginning`. Você está usando alguma biblioteca para JavaScript? Angular ou algo do gênero?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

É só criar um objeto do tipo `Date` e comparar normalmente se a primeira data é maior do que a segunda.

Uma dica é verificar se a data final é válida ao tentar sair do segundo input e, caso ela não seja, mostrar alguma mensagem e voltar o foco para o segundo `input`.

Perceba que a ideia de voltar o foco para input caso a entrada seja inválida parece interessante num primeiro momento, mas vai bloquear o usuário de tentar modificar a primeira data sem antes entrar com um intervalo válido. Ou seja, caso a primeira tenha sido digitada errada, o usuário vai precisar colocar uma data final válida para depois poder editar a data inicial.

Também é possível setar o atributo `min` do segundo input igual (ou maior) a data do primeiro assim que for clicado fora do primeiro input. Não vou fazer este exemplo em código porque não sei se caberia na pergunta do jeito que está e nem sei se isto te interessa.

```js
$('#date-form2').on('focusout', function(){  
  var dateObj1 = new Date($('#date-form1').val());
  var dateObj2 = new Date($('#date-form2').val());
  
  if(dateObj1.getTime() > dateObj2.getTime()){
    $(this).css({color: 'red'});
    // mostre alguma mensagem
    $(this).focus(); // Volta o foco para o segundo input
  }  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="date-form1">Data/Hora Inicio</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="datetime-local" name="date-beginning" id="date-form1">
</div>

<!-- Data Fim -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="date-form2">Data/Hora Fim</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="datetime-local" name="date-end" id="date-form2">
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda @jbueno! Mas porque vocês meteu aquela linha com a tag "<script>" antes do código html? E esse método onde compara as datas não tem de ser chamado em algum lado no html?

Comment: @VítorSá Aquilo é só uma referência pro jQuery. Eu fiz com jQuery pra ficar mais fácil de ler.